# How to prevent overlapping of nodes in the cytoscape dagre layout

Tags: cytoscape.js

tried the options like:

```
avoidOverlap: true, // prevents node overlap, may overflow boundingBox if not enough space
avoidOverlapPadding: 10, // extra spacing around nodes when avoidOverlap: true
nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: false, // Excludes the label when calculating node bounding boxes for the layout algorithm
spacingFactor: undefined,
```

but of no use in dagre layout....tried "nodeSep:1000" but the graph is too laggy as it effects all the nodes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the concentric layout, so I had to make a layout myself via:

```
cy.nodes("[id = '" + node + "']").shift('x', x);
cy.nodes("[id = '" + node + "']").shift('y', y);
```

If you don't find any other solution you can do this instead. I run the 'null' layout first and then get how many nodes I have in my cytoscape graph and with these information you can set your x and y coordinates according to that. It gets a little complicated, if you find a solution, please let me know.